# RedirectToAction is hit but not redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My redirect to action hits the method in the chatroom / index controllers but doesn't actually redirect the user, it just remains on the same page. How do i fix this? I can navigate to the views via the urls so there are no errors with regards to that.

Chatroom controller

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ChatRoom()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Home Controller

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(String username, String password)
    {
        bool ValidUser = UserDBController.ValidateUser(new Models.UserModel
        {
            UserName = username,
            PasswordHash = HashPass(password)
        });

        password = String.Empty;

        if (ValidUser)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
            return RedirectToAction("ChatRoom", "ChatRoom");
        }
        ViewBag.Username = username;
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

Index View

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

Login partial

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}


<div class="LoginForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 input">
            @Html.TextBox("Username", null, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "username", @placeholder = "Username", required = "required", value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.username) ? ViewBag.username : "" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.TextBox("Password", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password",  @id = "password", @placeholder = "Password", required = "required" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="login-btn btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.login-btn').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Login",
        data: {
            userName: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have ever any custom Authorize class? like  `UserAuthorize : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: If you debug, does it hit `Index()` method?

Comment: ahmeticat, No, not that I know of.
@SeM Yeah, Index is being hit when its incorrect and Chatroom() is being hit when its correct.

Comment: Do you have different `Login` and `Index` views?

Comment: @SeM . I have an index view that contains my login partial view. I'll update the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are doing ajax post. You can return url as a result and use that url to redirect.

Comment: Thanks. Implemented this.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Login function

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Login(String username, String password)
{
    ...

    if (ValidUser)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and your AJAX method

```
$('.login-btn').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Login",
            data: {
                userName: $('#username').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            },
            succcess:function (myJSONdata) {
                if(myJSONdata == true)
                    location.href = '/ChatRoom/ChatRoom';
                else
                    location.href = '/Home/Index';
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
        });
});
```